# Nodejs-Mongodb-native subdocument filter not working properly

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, node-mongodb-native

I am trying to fetch data from Mongodb from Nodejs code via MongoDB-Native driver. Here is model which I have in collection:

```
{
  name: 'Himkar Dwivedi',
  role: 'Software Engineer',
  address: {
    flat: '163',
    building: 'B6',
    area: 'DLF',
    contact: {
      type: 'phone',
      num: '910xxxx882'
    }
  }
}
```

I am getting proper response from below query:

```
{ role: 'Software Engineer',   name: 'Himkar Dwivedi',   'address.flat': '163' }
```

but I need to form query something like this: (true json query object)

```
{ role: 'Software Engineer',   name: 'Himkar Dwivedi',   address:{flat: '163' }}
```

Which is not giving any response to me. Please help me to get it resolve.

Comment: Your second query will only match documents where the entire `address` subdoc is `{flat: '163'}` (no other fields). That's why you need to use dot notation. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Thanks Johnny, I solved my problem using DOT. But it should support pure json query

Answer (score 0):

because when you use this query `address:{flat: '163' }` mongo search for a document like this :

```
{
  name: 'Himkar Dwivedi',
  role: 'Software Engineer',
  address: {
    flat: '163'
  }
}
```